# How to escape a special character (like \n) in Makefile

Tags: bash, makefile

I have a makefile, that compile some typescript into JavaScript, and adds the line "#!/usr/bin/env node" to the top of it.
The way I do the last thing, atm, is with this line

```
 echo "#!/usr/bin/env node\n$$(cat javascriptFile)" > javascriptFile;\
```

But what I notice is that, anywhere in the JavaScript where there is a \n, \t or similar, it gets converted to newline or tab, repectivly.

This cases some problems. Lets say I have a literal string "this is a \n string".
It ends up being

"this is a 
 string"

which is not valid JavaScript.

What I'm looking for is a way to keep those \n and \t when doing $$(cat file);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not related to make; if you ran that command in your shell prompt the same thing would happen.

The problem is that the shell is taking the output of the cat and passing it to echo.  Echo will automatically convert all these characters, that's why they're being converted (see the man page for echo).

Also, you can't cat a file and redirect it to the same file!

It's a really bad idea to have echo print anything but the simplest text.  You should rewrite your recipe like this:

```
( echo '#!/usr/bin/env node' ; cat javascriptFile ) > newJavascriptFile
mv newJavaScriptFile javascriptFile
```

Comment: Only with the `-e` option to `echo`, it seems.

Comment: You do bring up a good point, regarding the "echo $(cat file) > file", although this does not answer how I can avoid echo converting "\n" to newline, or provide an alternative for writing to a file without converting \n two new lines.

Thanks though.

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  I showed you exactly how to get the behavior you wanted, in my example.  Why do you want to use cat to generate the output of a file, pass it on the command line to echo, and have echo print it out?  That's a lot of unnecessary work, that causes a lot of problems.  Why not just have cat print it out directly, as I show in my answer?  The behavior of echo is not standardized so there's no portable way to do what you want.  The bash builtin version of echo supports the -E flag (run `help echo`).

Comment: But, if you suppress \n then the one you DO want (after `#!/usr/bin/env node`) will _also_ be suppressed.